# Best OpenCV algorithm for detecting fast moving ball?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am new to OpenCV. I am working on a project that involves tracking and detecting a spinning roulette ball. Here is the video I want to use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzZNaVQ3FnA&list=LL_a67IPXKsmu48W4swCQpMQ&index=7&t=0s

I want to get the ball time for 1 revolution. But the ball is quite fast and hard to detect. I am not sure how to overcome this.

What would be the best algorithm for doing this?

Comment: At what stage in the motion ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust In the start when the ball is spun, or a few revolutions after. Is it possible?

Comment: @user2651231 is there a chance of using a higher frame rate camera ? motion blur will be a real hassle otherwise

Comment: Interesting problem, but you need to clarify the constraints. If the camera is fixed the problem is trivial: just mask a window in the frame across the roulette's backtrack (the area where the ball is spun), and threshold, there is no need to track to get an approximate speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By subtracting successive images, you will isolate the ball as a (slightly curved) line segment. Both its length and its angular position are cues for the speed.

Anyway, these parameters are a little tricky to extract for a side view, as the ellipse has to be "unprojected" to a top view, to see the original circle. You need to know the relative position of the wheel and the viewer, which you most probably don't know.

An approximate solution is obtained by stretching the ellipse in the direction of the small axis.

[image]

Comment: The camera is fixed. But after a few revolutions, the camera zooms in. I am only interested in the ball when the camera is zoom out.